# Gulp, browserify and remapify

Tags: coffeescript, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to find a nice way to map directories with browserify and gulp so I don't have lots of paths link this:

```
var uriparser = require('../../../app/assets/javascripts/app/module/mymodule.coffee')
```

So I have been trying to use remapify with gulp so I have recipe like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var remapify = require('remapify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task("test", function () {
  var b = browserify({entries:['./spec/javascripts/modules/tests.coffee'],
    extensions: ['.coffee']
  });

  b.plugin(remapify, [
    {
      src: './app/assets/javascripts/app/**/*.coffee'
      , expose: 'app'
      , cwd:__dirname
    }

  ])



  libs.forEach(function (lib) {
    b.external(lib);
  });



  return b.bundle()
    .pipe(source("app.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./spec/javascripts/specs/helpers'));
});
```

Not sure what I am missing, but it simply not mapping the paths correctly, maybe this isn't the best tool, but have tried quite a few options with no success, so any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You have at least one problem, due to: https://github.com/joeybaker/remapify/pull/4.

Remapify currently does not support extensions like "coffee". You can use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee to compile your CoffeeScript into JavaScript first and then remapify it.

Answer (score 1):

Remapify now respects the list of extensions configured in browserify.  By default this is `js` and `json`, but you can change it by the `extensions` browserify option.   Not sure what the format would be in gulp, but here's what I'm doing in grunt:

```
  grunt.initConfig
    browserify:
      app:
        dest: 'public/scripts/main.js'
        src: ['client/app/**/*.coffee']
        options:
          preBundleCB: (b) ->
            b.plugin remapify, [
              cwd: './client/app'
              src: '**/*.coffee'
              expose: 'app'
            ]

          transform: ['coffeeify']
          browserifyOptions:
            debug: true
            extensions: ['.coffee', '.js']
```